# Email reset password in Office365 using powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

When I reset a password in the Office 365 Admin portal, I have the option to send the new password in an email, without me even seeing the password first.

[image]

I know I can reset the password with

```
Set-MsolUserPassword
```

Can I also trigger the password email to an email address of my choice from Powershell - like in the UI? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

One tweak to Mike111b's email:

You could simply use:

```
$Password = Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName <UPN>
```

Then use the Send-MailMessage command.

The Set-MsolUserPassword command returns the password as an output so it can be saved to a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah.  Check out the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage

Very basic implementation:

```
$UserPrincipalName = Read-Host "Enter the UserPrincipalName"
$Password = Read-Host "Enter the new password"

Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName "$UserPrincipalName" -NewPassword "$Password"

Send-MailMessage -To "$UserPrincipalName" -From "ENTER YOUR EMAIL HERE" -Subject "Password Reset" -Body "I have reset your password.  Your new password is:`n`n$Password"
```

The authentication against the sender field is by default authenticated against the current user.  If that doesn't work for you you can use the -Credential parameter.

I would also recommend randomizing each password.  Whether that be from an online tool then pasted into PowerShell or done right in PowerShell it doesn't matter but I would make it a priority.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?  If I didn't answer your question accurately let me know and I can help you get to the right solution.

Comment: The original question was how to do this "without me even seeing the password first.", so your solution using `read-host` isn't what they were looking for.